# What if a bullet hit Wonder Woman?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

What happens if Wonder Woman didn't deflect a bullet with her bracelets and if it hit her in her head or non-armoured part of her body, would the bullet penetrate her body?

Comment: Related [scifi.se] question: [**Is Wonder Woman invincible?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162731/21267)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### She would be injured, but she does have superpowered healing abilities

---

During the first battle scene on Themyscira, Diana does sustain an injury/flesh wound on her left arm which the movie seems to imply was a deflected bullet.

This happens when Antiope sacrifices herself for Diana (probably deflecting the trajectory of the bullet to save her)
[image]
[image]

This implies that the DCEU version of Wonder Woman, at least at this point in her timeline, can have her skin broken by bullets or kinds of trajectories (like shrapnel).

Later on, though, the healer removes her bandages and sees her skin has healed fully, surprising her

[image]

> **HEALER:** Strange...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63634/discussion-on-answer-by-ghoti-and-chips-what-if-a-bullet-hit-wonder-woman).

Answer (score 10):

Since we don't see it happen in the movie, we can only speculate.

There is some evidence that being shot might hurt (but not penetrate) since she feels pain when training early in the movie and is, initially, forbidden edged weapons.

However, when Diana comes into her powers, it seems she obtains "god-level" power (or at least demi-god) and is **probably** invulnerable to pretty much everything....even if, at the time, she isn't aware of it.

Ares even says that..

> "only a god can kill another god"

..so it seems likely that a bullet might sting but **not penetrate and/or kill**.

Using the bracelets is more of a "convenience" than a necessity.

In the comics her powers have fluctuated over the years to Superman level (and beyond). For more on that I suggest you see this [Q&A over at Science Fiction & Fantasy Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81742/does-wonder-woman-need-to-use-her-bracelets)

Comment: The reason Hippolyta doesn't want Wonder Woman near edged weapons when she is young is probably because if she'd get injured she would find out she can heal really fast, essentially raising suspicion about her superpowers and literal divinity (which she was trying to hide from her, since it linked her to Ares).

Comment: @GhotiandChips plus, the illegitimate human children of Zeus have a long history (in Greek mythology) of getting a lot of flak from his wife. It is probable that a degree of protection from Hera necessitated hiding her powers. It is prossible that everyone was willing to ignore the situation (or rather not tell Hera) if Wonder Woman didn't know and just lived a human life.

Comment: @Typhon I don't know that we can use actual Greek mythology to map onto Wonder Woman, which is very loosely inspired by Greek mythology, especially the DCEU Wonder Woman which seems stray from actual comic book lore here and there. I'd rather, when commenting on the Wonder Woman movie from the DCEU, work with what we're given, rather than make suppositions based on assumptions we don't know are valid.

Comment: @GhotiandChips I was merely adding another level to the whole thing since you said her powers linked her to Ares. I figured another valid possibility would also be to hide her from Hera so she doesn't get generally angry at anyone who might've known about Diana.

Comment: @Typhon Hera isn't even mentioned in the entire movie, so that seems, again, like baseless speculation. I lean more on the stronger evidence that suggests Hippolyta wanted a simple, peaceful life for her, her "daughter" and her people. She persistently pretends Ares is either dead or not a problem (until she has no choice but to face the truth), so it's quite obvious, to me, from what we're presented, that she didn't want her "daughter" finding out about her powers because it'd raise questions that would lead her to fulfill her dangerous destiny.

Comment: @GhotiandChips what destiny? She goes after Ares to stop the war and afaik Zeus isn't in the movie either... Plus since when is that question *not* a purely speculative one?

Comment: @Typhon Zeus _is_ in the movie in that he is mentioned, he's referenced multiple time, he's even shown on screen via CGI flashback/storytelling, and it is revealed to Diana that he is her father. Meanwhile Hera is never mentioned. It's a folly interaction at this point.

Comment: @Typhon It is her destiny to kill Ares in that Zeus made her for the objective to kill Ares, and she was even codenamed Godkiller etc. Speculation's fine, but weak assumptions and baseless speculation isn't something I'm gonna waste time on, though (and I'm telling you this because you tagged me with your comment where you presented suppositions based on weak assumptions).